# Is this equation of the tangent line correct?

Tags: calculus

This is a 2 part question, I figured out the first part easily but don't understand what to plug in to get the second part.

**PART a:**
Use the definition of derivative to calculate the *f '(x)* for *f(x)= sqrt[x]*

I got *1/2sqrt[x]* as the derivative.

**PART b**
Use the result in (a), find the equation of the tangent line to the curve of
*f (x)=sqrt[x] at x=4*.

**Plugging the numbers into the formula *y-y1=m(x-x1)* I get *y-2=1/4(x-4)*, is this correct or have I made an error?**

Comment: What did you learn from posting your previous question?

Comment: $y-y1=m(x-x1)$ is exactly right.  If, for some reason, you think this is leading to an erroneous result, then edit your query to show your work.  Then, a mathSE reviewer will respond to your **shown** work.  Please do **not** respond with a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula for a straight line, as you mentioned, is
$$y=m(x-x_1)+y_1$$ where $m$ is the slope and $y_1$ is the value for $y$ when $x=x_1$. A more convenient notation, is writing $y$ as a function of "$x$" ($y=T(x)$. I use "$T$" for tangent) so we'd have
$$T(x)=m(x-x_1)+T(x_1)$$
(notice that we have $y_1=T(x_1)$ since, as I just stated, "$y_1$ is the value for $y$ when $x=x_1$", that is, $T(x_1)$).
But we want $T$ to be a function (a straight line) that describes the tangent at a point, say $\bar x$, for a function $f$ so it ought be the case that $T(\bar x)=f(\bar x)$. To ensure this, we set $\bar x=x_1$ (now, we have a line $T$ that passes through $(\bar x, f(\bar x))$, the desired point). All that's left is the slope $m$. As I'm sure you are aware, the slope of our desired tangent is $f'(\bar x)$ (so $m=f'(\bar x)$). Now we have
$$T(x)=f'(\bar x)(x-\bar x)+f(\bar x) \tag{$\star$}$$
This is the *general formula for the tangent line of a function $f$ at $\bar x$*.
If we let $\bar x= 4$ and $f(x)=\sqrt x$ then $\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$ and we have a tangent line
$$T(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4}}(x-4)+\sqrt4 .$$
Make sure you undertsand $(\star)$ and remember it.